# Resharper does not suggest parameter name in method signature

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharpen used to suggest a name for a parameter (almost similar to the type name) when creating a method or constructor. It seems that i lost this functionality, any help on how to regain it?

```
void SomeMethod(SomeType resharperSuggestedName)
```

Comment: What you have appears to be what Resharper would suggest.. therefore it isn't required.,

Comment: With your example, after typing `void SomeMethod(SomeType ` I would expect to have to do a Ctrl+Space to get R# to suggest some parameter names; I don't think it's ever popped up a list automatically